# how do I get my altair plot from views to render on my html page in Django?

Tags: python, django, altair, vega

I am trying to get my Altair plot to render from my views to my html page. I have tried everything from stack overflow to get this to work, but every time I try I don't get my plot. This is my code in the different sections.

Views.py:

```
def search_site(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        inputSite = request.POST.get('Site')
        SITES = Ericsson_LTE_1D_Version_Sectir_ID_HOUR.objects.filter(SITE__contains = inputSite).values()
        data = pd.DataFrame(SITES)
        chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
        y ='Avg_Nr_Of_RRC_Connected_Users:Q',
        x ='PERIOD_START_TIME:T',
        ).to_json(indent=None)

        
        return render(request,'VenueReporting/searchSite.html', {'site':inputSite,'Predictions':SITES,'chart':chart})
    else:
        return render(request, 'VenueReporting/searchSite.html',{})
```

HTML Page:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@[VERSION]"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@[VERSION]"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@[VERSION]"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = "{{chart}}";
    vegaEmbed('#vis1', chart).then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(console.warn);
  </script>

    {% if Predictions %}
        <h2>You Searched for:</h2>
        <h3>{{site}}</h3>
        <h2>The activity was:</h2>
        <div id="vis1"></div>
    
    {% else %}
        <h1>That Venue does not exist or you put the wrong information</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chart` variable in the javascript should not be a string, it should be a JSON object. Also, django's default behavior of escaping special charcters will result in invalid JSON. To fix this, you can use something like this (notice there are no quotes):

```javascript
var chart = {{ chart|safe }};
```

Also, in your `<script>` tags, `[VERSION]` is not meant to be used literally. You should specify the versions of the libraries compatible with Altair, which you can find in `alt.VEGA_VERSION`, `alt.VEGAEMBED_VERSION`, and `alt.VEGALITE_VERSION`:

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@{{ alt.VEGA_VERSION }}"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@{{ alt.VEGALITE_VERSION }}"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@{{ alt.VEGAEMBED_VERSION }}"></script>
```

(assuming you pass `alt` to your template).

Comment: It's still not working. How do I pass alt to my template? Also for the JavaScript it says, "property assignment expected" as its highlighted in red.

Comment: okay i fixed the "Property assignment error" but I still am not getting a plot. I also still dont know how to pass alt to my template

Comment: okay I figured it out the problem was my javascript needed to be after my div call